# Connection timeout with HttpURLConnection in Groovy

Tags: url, groovy

I am always getting the "Error Connecting to ${url}" message?

Can anyone please show me my mistake?

```
        def url = new URL("https://www.google.com")
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
        // connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
        connection.connect()
        if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201) {
            def returnMessage = connection.content

            //print out the full response
            println returnMessage
        } else {
            println "Error Connecting to " + url
        }
```

| Error 2012-07-05 00:04:05,950 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - ConnectException occurred when processing request: [GET] /CopperApplications/urlTracker Connection timed out: connect. Stacktrace follows: Message: Connection timed out: connec

Comment: What `responseCode` are you actually getting? That would be useful information to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: | Error 2012-07-05 00:04:05,950 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ConnectException occurred when processing request: [GET] /CopperApplications/urlTracker
Connection timed out: connect. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: @sam1132 - Please edit your question in include that error message. It is useful for people trying to answer your question and should be part of the question, and not just in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried it with different URLs? including non-HTTPS URLs?

Comment: Yeah i used http and few internal sites too i always get this timeout error

Comment: To see if it is a bug with your code you can try a more simple case. Try including this line and see what happens: `println 'http://www.google.com'.toURL().text`

If that doesn't work it could be a configuration problem with your machine, firewall, or network; rather than with your code itself.

Comment: @David Yeah I can actually c the HTML code in my console

Comment: I don't think there's much more I can suggest. I can tell you that the code works on my machine; and we can verify that your machine is able to connect and return HTML from remote site.

Comment: @David Thx for ur help i m using HTTP Builder n its working f9

Comment: Agreed. The code works for me too, except I modified the content print to use `println "${returnMessage}";` otherwise, it just prints **sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@5f30b97d**.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, and produces the expected(?) results on Groovy 1.7.9 with 1.6.0_33 JVM. There is likely something amiss with your network (as indicated by the connection timeout error).