# How to execute url in groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I want to call a with the format `http://x.x.x.x/test/test.jsp?[params]` in Groovy. In this file I am getting `params` value from the URL for further processing.
However, I want to know how to call this URL from Groovy in the first place.

I tried this bit it didn't work:
(I *am* new to Groovy, to be fair.)

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.87:8080/bridge/test.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Comment: You can use e.g. `"http://192.168.1.87:8080/bridge/test.php".toURL().text`

Comment: will that run script which I have added in test.php for testing purpose ? @Opal

Comment: It will make a HTTP GET request to specified URL.

Comment: ok let me try if it's work.. Thanks in advance @Opal

Comment: if something Does Not Work™ please add the error, the stacktrace, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code works for me :

```
def url = new URL("http://X.X.X.X:8080/url?[params]")
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
// connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.connect()
if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201) {
    def returnMessage = connection.content
} else {
}
```

Refrence : [Connection timeout with HttpURLConnection in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337795/connection-timeout-with-httpurlconnection-in-groovy)

Comment: since this is in the first few lines basically the same as the code in the question, what changed, that it works now?

Comment: for me it works cause I am not printing response. @cfrick

Comment: how to close this connection??